# Accessing Celery Group Task Results inside a Celery Worker

Tags: python, celery, task

I have to spawn certain tasks and have them execute in parallel. However I also need to have all their results of all these updated centrally.

Is it possible to access the results of all these tasks within a parent task somehow? I know I cant call a task_result.get() from a tasks since Celery doesnt allow it, is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can make Celery wait for the result of a subtask (see [`disable_sync_subtasks`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult.get) parameter to `get()`), it's just not recommended because you could deadlock the worker (see [here](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#avoid-launching-synchronous-subtasks) for more details). So if you use it, you should know what you are doing.

The recommended way for your use case is to use a [chord](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#chords):

> A chord is just like a group but with a callback. A chord consists of a header group and a body, where the body is a task that should execute after all of the tasks in the header are complete.

This would indeed require you to refactor your logic a bit so you don't need the subtasks' results inside the parent task but to process it in the chord's body.